# Integral of sine raised to a fractional power: $\int_\frac{-1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} \vert \sin(\pi f)\vert^{2d} df$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How would I go about evaluating the following integral? Let $d\in [-1/2,1/2]$. Its related to the spectral density function of a fractionally differenced processes.

$$\int_\frac{-1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} \vert \sin(\pi f)\vert^{2d} df$$

I know that the integral is finite, since it is bounded by unity over an interval of finite length, but I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Comment: There is a factor of 2 missing in the so-called identity. See [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50447/integration-of-powers-of-the-sin-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral does not converge for $d = -\frac{1}{2}$, but it does converge for all the other $d$. Let $d \in (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$. Since the integrand is an even function, you can write your integral as

$$2\int_0^{1/2}|\sin(\pi f)|^{2d}\, df.$$

Via the $u$-substitution $u = \pi f$, we get

$$ 2\int_0^{\pi/2} |\sin u|^{2d} \frac{du}{\pi} = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2d}(u)\, du = \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(d + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(d + 1)},$$

using the identity

> $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2x-1}(u)\cos^{2y-1}(u)\, du = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x + y)},\quad x,y > 0.$$

Since $\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2}) = \sqrt{\pi}$,

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\Gamma\left(d + \frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(d + 1)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\Gamma\left(d + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(d + 1)}.$$

So for $d\in (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$,

$$\int_{-1/2}^{1/2}|\sin(\pi f)|^{2d}\, df = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{\Gamma\left(d + \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma(d + 1)}.$$

Comment: Thanks @kobe, what about if instead of $\pi f$ we have $2^n \pi \theta$?