# Prove that $1<\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}dx<\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$using integration.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, area, integral-inequality

Prove that $$1<\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}dx<\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ using integration.

**My Attempt**

I tried using the Jordan's inequality
$$\frac{2}{\pi}x\leq\sin x<1$$
Taking square root throughout
$$\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi}}\leq \sqrt{\sin x}<1$$
On integrating throughout
$$1<\frac{\pi}{3}\leq \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{\sin x}dx<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

But I am not getting $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ as required.

Comment: try using a stronger upper bound $\sin x < x.$ If this does not give the answer, split the integration bound as $[0,1]$ and $[1, \pi/2]$ and on the latter use $\sin x < 1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do better: using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50447)
$$
\int _0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(x)} \,dx = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2 \approx 1.19
$$

If you want a numerical answer,
$$
\int _0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin(x)}\,dx > \int _0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\,dx = 1
$$
On the other hand, by Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz
$$
\left(\int _0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin(x)}\,dx\right)^2\leq \left(\int _0^{\pi/2} 1\,dx \right)\cdot \left(\int _0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\,dx \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: OTOH? ${{{{}}}}$

Comment: On the $\{\text{one},\text{other}\}$ hand; meaning by context

Answer (score 11):

You can use Holder's inequality:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(x)}\, dx \leq \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\, dx\right)^{1/2} = \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{1/2}\,.
$$

Answer (score 4):

The upper bound can be obtained  Jensen's inequality
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(x)}\,dx \leq \Big(\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x)\, dx\Big)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
$$
from where

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\sin(x)}\,dx\leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

The lower bound follows from $0\leq \sin x\leq \sqrt{\sin x}$ in $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: Is Jensen's inequality valid in process of definite integration. Can it be proved